# Compare 2 class elements in Python

Tags: python-2.7, compare

I have a class defined below:

```
class Members(object):
   def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age):
      self.first_name = first_name
      self.last_name = last_name
      self.age = age
```

I then created 2 lists containing instances of the class:

```
CourseA = []
CourseB = []

// Extract (multiple) first_name, last_name, age from a file
CourseA.append(Members(first_name, last_name, age)) # called multiple times

// Extract (multiple) first_name, last_name, age from a file
CourseB.append(Members(first_name, last_name, age)) # called multiple times
```

So basically I have 2 lists like the following:

```
# CourseA
John, Smith, 12
Jane, Doe, 14
Susan, Patton, 13

# CourseB
Richard, Lane, 12
Susan, Patton, 13
```

Now I want to compare the `first_name` and `last_name` of `CourseA` and `CourseB`. If both are the same, then print the corresponding age. In this case, "Susan Patton" is the common name in both lists, so I would print "13".

What is the most efficient way to do this? Both lists are huge, and I thought of comparing one name from `CourseA` to all names in `CourseB`, then compare the next name in `CourseA` to all names in `CourseB`, but this seems like a very slow method.

ETA: So now I have included the following in the class definition.

```
def __hash__(self):
   return hash((self.first_name, self.last_name))

def __eq__(self):
   try:
        return (self.first_name, self.last_name) == (other.first_name, other.last_name)
   except AttributeError:
        return False
```

Then, I have the following to do the comparison. BTW, it seems like the comparison below works even without the `__eq__` and `__hash__` in my class definitions.

```
CourseA_set = set((x.first_name, x.last_name) for x in CourseA)
CourseB_set = set((y.first_name, y.last_name) for y in CourseB)

for (caller, callee) in CourseA_set.intersection(CourseB_set):
   print ("Found: {0}".format((caller, callee)))
```

I do get the `first_name` and `last_name` that is found in both `CourseA` and `CourseB`. However, how do I get the other corresponding attributes from `CourseA` and `CourseB`, like `age`?

Do I have to search through the `CourseA` and `CourseB` lists for matching `(first_name, last_name)` to get the corresponding age? This seems to be inefficient.

Comment: If you implement `__eq__` and `__hash__`, you could to this easily with set operations.

Comment: What should happen in case of difference in age?

Comment: @frist It should print both ages

Comment: As @jonrsharpe suggested you have to implement [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) (or [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)) methods to use instances in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Note however that in case of implemented `__hash__` method your instances should be immutable.

Comment: I've modified the code, but am still having some trouble getting the other attributes of the class, i.e. age. Please see OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the class instances with tuples containing their attributes. You should instead keep the instances as they are in the lists, then turn the lists into sets without stripping the attributes off the class

```
CourseA_set = set(CourseA) # no set comprehension
CourseB_set = set(CourseB)

for member in CourseA_set.intersection(CourseB_set):
     print ("Found: {f} {l} {a}".format(f=member.first_name, 
                                        l=member.last_name, 
                                        a=member.age))
```

The `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods you already implemented will ensure only the instances with matching `first_name` and `last_name` from both sets are kept after doing the intersection.

Comment: Won't this be matching all 3 attributes? I'm actually trying to match on only `first_name` and `last_name`, then print the value of `age` from both lists corresponding to the match.

Comment: No it won't. Your `__hash__` and `__eq__` were implemented on `first_name` and `last_name`, so `age` will not be considered

Comment: Thanks! I do get all the attributes this way. But it seems to get the attributes from `CourseB` only. How can I print the attributes from `CourseA` as well, because the `age` may be different.

Comment: Another complication is when there is more than one entry in either `CourseA` or `CourseB` with the same matching `(first_name,last_name)` but with different `age`. I would like to print all the ages in this case too. Now it seems like using `set` means I can't keep track of the indices of such cases. Otherwise, perhaps I could have used the indices to print the corresponding `age`. Although it means I have to do an entry-by-entry search, which is slow...

Comment: Intersection picks one unique item common to both. If they're all from `B` that shouldn't be considered a problem. With your current implementation of the class, members with matching first and last names will be eliminated leaving only one by the set operation. You may add a new attribute that distinguishes such duplicate cases to your `__hash__` and `__eq__`.